# forName does not find class

Tags: android, class

I would have expected both the following assignments to be valid, but the second one raises a class not found exception. Any ideas?

```
missionIntent = new Intent(this, Mission00.class);
/*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Checking Mission00 by class");

missionIntent = new Intent(this, Class.forName("Mission00"));
/*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Checking Mission00 by string");
```

I've also tried Class.forName("Mission00.class") but that doesn't work either

Comment: Try "Mission00" qualified with the package before it: "com.package.something.Mission00".

Comment: Yeah, that works. How can I find the prefix? this.getClass().getName() returns "com.package.something.currentClass", can I find the prefix without doing string manipulation? Please post as answer so I can give you some points!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try "Mission00" qualified with the package before it: "com.package.something.Mission00".  Since you have the class name already, you should have the package name but you can use `this.getClass.getPackage()` to get the prefix, as you previously asked for.

Comment: Cheers for the help. Actually I used this.getPackageName(), but your answer (and your first comment) showed me the way!

Answer (score 7):

Use the fully qualified class name, including package.